# Can I get Average sleep analytics from HealthKit?

Tags: ios, healthkit

For `HKQuantityType` like steps I can use `HKStatisticsCollectionQuery` to get sum of all steps on the interval, in my case day, without worrying about deduplicate date since HealthKit handle that for me.

But Sleep Analytics is `HKCategoryType` and from what I know `HKStatisticsCollectionQuery` doesn't support this type. This mean I have to query all the samples and dedup it my own?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no equivalent of `HKStatisticsCollectionQuery` for `HKCategoryTypes` in HealthKit.

Comment: So we have to query sample out and handle everything including dedup multiple source ourself?

Comment: Yes, you would have to deduplicate yourself.